# What is the correct way to do stuff before a node is shutdown?

Tags: ros, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do some shutting down code for my node.
It is important that I am still fully connected to ROS while that is happening, so putting stuff just after the main loop is not an option.

Currently I would pass NoSigIntHandler to ros::init,
install my own SIGINT handler, do stuff there and then call ros::shutdown.

Is this correct, i.e. the intended way or is there a better solution?

Update: I tested this and it works fine for pressing Ctrl-C even from roslaunch. For me this is OK right now.

The only thing that does not work is what Lorenz hinted at: rosnode kill seems to use another method, I get:

```
[ WARN] [1329394338.937166789, 61.017000000]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1329394338.937223749, 61.017000000]: Reason given for shutdown: [user request]
```

and my SIGINT handler is not called.
I could try to work around this by checking `ros::isShuttingDown` and trying to shutdown my stuff while that is happening, but that doesn't seem safe to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27655/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-stuff-before-a-node-is-shutdown?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 22

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-15**:
I see at least one (possible) problem with your solution: will it handle a `rosnode kill` command, i.e. a shutdown triggered via xmlrpc? I don't know a better solution though.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-15**:
Seems reasonable to me.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-15**:
@Lorenz: Depends on what rosnode kill does. Does it send SIGINT/SIGTERM? I'll play around with this tomorrow.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-16**:
Rosnode kill cannot send SIGINT if the node is not owned by the user executing rosnode or if the node is running on a different computer. As far as I know, it uses the shutdown XMLRPC call (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Slave_API).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-16**:
Yep, just found that out by trying. The only question left would be: Is it possible to hook in there and stop the shutdown until I am done. I'm OK with Ctrl-C handling for now as I don't use rosnode kill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two normal ways to tell a node to shut down:

- SIGINT signal. Used by `roslaunch` or when you do `Ctrl-C`.
- Shutdown XMLRPC call. Used by `rosnode kill`.

If you want to cover all your bases, you need to override roscpp's handlers for both. In practice, most people seem to just override SIGINT, probably because it's actually documented and `rosnode kill` is less-used.

What roscpp really needs is an "on shutdown" callback. That's ticketed here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3417

In the meantime, it is possible (if a little messy) to do this correctly. An example is the [nodelet.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/unstable/api/nodelet/html/nodelet_8cpp_source.html) code. The relevant parts look like:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/xmlrpc_manager.h>

// Signal-safe flag for whether shutdown is requested
sig_atomic_t volatile g_request_shutdown = 0;

// Replacement SIGINT handler
void mySigIntHandler(int sig)
{
  g_request_shutdown = 1;
}

// Replacement "shutdown" XMLRPC callback
void shutdownCallback(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue& params, XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue& result)
{
  int num_params = 0;
  if (params.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray)
    num_params = params.size();
  if (num_params > 1)
  {
    std::string reason = params[1];
    ROS_WARN("Shutdown request received. Reason: [%s]", reason.c_str());
    g_request_shutdown = 1; // Set flag
  }

  result = ros::xmlrpc::responseInt(1, "", 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Override SIGINT handler
  ros::init(argc, argv, "MyNode", ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
  signal(SIGINT, mySigIntHandler);

  // Override XMLRPC shutdown
  ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->unbind("shutdown");
  ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->bind("shutdown", shutdownCallback);

  // Create publishers, subscribers, etc.

  // Do our own spin loop
  while (!g_request_shutdown)
  {
    // Do non-callback stuff

    ros::spinOnce();
    usleep(100000);
  }

  // Do pre-shutdown tasks

  ros::shutdown();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-04-19**:
Is this in the documentation? I couldn't find it. If not, it should be added, IMO.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-07-13**:
There ought to be a `ros::NodeHandler nh;` in there in order for the node to appear under rosnode list and be rosnode killable.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-07-13**:
Also http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/nodelet/html/nodelet_8cpp_source.html#l00314 could replace the dead nodelet.cpp link, but is also more complicated.

**Comment by [khaiyichin](https://answers.ros.org/users/43473/khaiyichin/) on 2019-10-25**:
does anyone know if that ticket (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3417) still exists?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2019-10-25**:
@khaiyichin it does not exist. Bear in mind that this discussion is 7 years old.

Comment: Looks like wayback archived some of code.ros.org but not the trac part, or it's at a url I can't find https://web.archive.org/web/20111111231714/https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at roscpp, the current handler on SIGINT just call `ros::requestShutdown()` so you should fine be with your current solution.

See:
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/tags/electric/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/init.cpp

On a different point, requesting a shutdown on ROS just switch a boolean variable (see the previous source code) so IMHO it should be safe to continue using ROS after resquestShutdown is called... Maybe someone can confirm?

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-16**:
What I'm worried about is: For how long. The shutdown will surely happen quite timely and I have no guarantees. I have digged a bit through the code. I could try getting a lock on the global shutdown mutex, but interfering here seems quite risky to me.